# Visual Studio 2012 - corrupted .cs file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Few hours ago I started a new project. I pretty much finished it up, but I was making some performance tests with it. During those tests my PC suddenly crashed, so I needed to restart it.

After reboot, when I open my project, my main .cs file doesn't want to open! When I click on it in visual studio, it opens a blank notepad file! How do I retrieve my code from that file? Almost all of my code was in it...

Comment: If Visual Studio didn't prompt for a recovery .. I'd start by writing it over (and better). Although, there still might be a "temp" file floating about somewhere ..

Comment: what's the size of the .cs file?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it is not a VS related question but file recovery based one.

If you ever saved your file, chances are that you can recover them. [Winhex](http://www.winhex.com/winhex/hex-editor.html) is a good tool to recover deleted files. Here is [how](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=873c647LVm0).

If you never saved, chances are very bleak.

Comment: Yes I saved this file and it is on my hard drive, it says it has 4KB, can winhex recover/open files that exist?

Comment: I am not sure. They are different physical files. (One that is deleted, and one that is on disk).  If deleted file is not overwritten (on actual physical storage, chances depends upon many factors, most notably free space), it can be recovered. Winhex is a very powerful tool. But I am not sure about this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem few days ago. My PC restart suddenly and all file that is opened in VS is no longer work.

Try to open this file in Sublime text and Notepad++. If this will open file then you can copy it otherwise their is no way to read that stream that is look like `$$%%$%%$#^%#^$`

What I do is coding back from backup copy and spent my few more hour to recover my work by doing it again.

I believe if your code is personal then you should backup it or try private git (bitbucket,github) somewhere so you can easily get your thing back instead of 100% total lose of data.

Comment: I had the same situation and same learning. Whatever you do, Please save it.